# Is it possible to use different tsconfig file for vitest

Tags: typescript, rollupjs, vitest

Is there any way to use different tsconfig file for vitest?

I have a large project using vue-cli. Before converting it to vite based I first want to use vitest instead of jest. The problem is that the tsconfig.json file is using 'target: es2015' and for vitest it should be 'target: esnext'

Comment: searching for the same

Comment: One of the good things about vitest is that you can reuse your rollup and ts config to avoid extra configurations. I'm not sure that there is easy way to override tsconfig

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible via the `typecheck.tsconfig` option in your vitest configuration. [This is the relevant part of the documentation](https://vitest.dev/config/#typecheck-tsconfig).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we could set a path to a different tsconfig in the vitest configuration. However, I couldn't find such an option.

A workaround that might work in some scenarios would be an inverted pattern:

- Instead of having a main `tsconfig.json` to build the project and a `tsconfig.test.json` to run the tests
- We could use `tsconfig.json` for editor support inside the whole project (including tests) and for defining the test tsconfig options (vitest will pick those up)

  - Then use a separate `tsconfig.build.json` to define only build relevant settings (`tsc -p ./tsconfig.build.json`)

This allows to limit emitted build output by `rootDir`, `include`, etc.